# AngularMyDatepicker package showing compatible issue in Angular16

Tags: date, datepicker, compatibility, angular16

In my angular project I'm using angular-mydatepicker package version of 0.11.5.This is the latest version of this package according to documentation when I upgrade my project from angular 15to angular 16 it is showing error that this package is not compatible to angular 16.is there any solution to this issue.